# what's wrong with the implementation of this async chain?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the code below in a console app. The LookUpUser method gets called and PostAsJsonAsync gets called but breakpoints in the response checking don't get hit afterwards.  What am I doing incorrectly in this implementation?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestUseCase().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task TestUseCase()
{
    await GetUserGuids();
}

private static async Task GetUserGuids()
{
    var userGuids = new List<Guid>();
    userGuids.Add(Guid.Parse("7b5cf09c-196c-4e0b-a0e2-0683e4f11213"));
    userGuids.Add(Guid.Parse("3a636154-b7fc-4d96-9cd1-d806119ff79f"));
    userGuids.ForEach(async x => await LookUpUser(x));
}

private static async Task LookUpUser(Guid adUserGuid)
{
    var client = new HttpClientManager().GetHttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/users/search", new { ADUserGuid = adUserGuid });
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var groups = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>();
    }
    else //not 200
    {
        var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark `main` as `async` and just call `await TestUseCase();`, I'm not sure that is your problem though.

Comment: @RonBeyer marking main as async returns the following error: 
 "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point."  this is a C# console app btw.

Comment: You must be using an older C# version, [7.1 allows `async main`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/).

Comment: @Ron when I open VS2017 > Help, it shows "Visual C# 2017."  Is that different than C# 7.1?  If so then how can I upgrade the C# version?

Comment: Do you have the latest updates installed? You can switch language versions by going to the project Properties > Build Tab, then at the very bottom select the "Advanced" button and select the language version in the first drop down. Notice though that it should be `public static async Task Main()`, not void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 userGuids.ForEach(async x => await LookUpUser(x));
```

The delegate in the `ForEach` is basically a `async void` (fire and forget)

Consider selecting a collection of `Task` and then use `Task.WhenAll`

```
private static async Task GetUserGuids() {
    var userGuids = new List<Guid>();
    userGuids.Add(Guid.Parse("7b5cf09c-196c-4e0b-a0e2-0683e4f11213"));
    userGuids.Add(Guid.Parse("3a636154-b7fc-4d96-9cd1-d806119ff79f"));
    var tasks = userGuids.Select(x => LookUpUser(x)).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Also assuming `HttpClientManager.GetHttpClient()` returns a `HttpClient` there is no need to create multiple instances. on static client should do

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClientManager().GetHttpClient();
private static async Task LookUpUser(Guid adUserGuid) {
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/users/search", new { ADUserGuid = adUserGuid });
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var groups = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>();
    } else  {
        //not 200
        var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the change you mentioned above but I'm still encountering the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by changing the ForEach to:

```
foreach (var guid in userGuids)
{
    await LookUpUserInSecurityApi(guid);
}
```

Comment: Yep, using the `ForEach` method creates tasks that the main method doesn't wait for.

Comment: this essentially is what NKosi's answer achieves and should've worked